# Why do I get dependency-error trying to install package "tidytext" in RStudio

Tags: install.packages, tidytext

I tried to install tidytext package and received below dependency-ERROR.  Please help.

ERROR: dependency ‘ISOcodes’ is not available for package ‘stopwords’
ERROR: dependency ‘stopwords’ is not available for package ‘tidytext’

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to install the [ISOcodes](https://cran.r-project.org/package=ISOcodes) package. Try that out:

```r
install.packages("ISOcodes")
```